# How to work with PySpark, SparkSQL and Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a bit confused with the different actors in this story: PySpark, SparkSQL, Cassandra and the pyspark-cassandra connector.

As I understand Spark evolved quite a bit and SparkSQL is now a key component (with the 'dataframes'). Apparently there is absolutely no reason to work without SparkSQL, especially if connecting to Cassandra.

So my question is: what component are needed and how do I connect them together in the simplest way possible?

With `spark-shell` in Scala I could do simply

```
./bin/spark-shell --jars spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.6.0-M1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and then

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext
val cc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
cc.setKeyspace("mykeyspace")
val dataframe = cc.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable group by beamstamp")
```

How can I do that with `pyspark`?

Here are a couple of subquestions along with partial answers I have collected (correct if I'm wrong).

- Is pyspark-casmandra needed (I don't think so - I don't understand what is was doing in the first place)
- Do I need to use `pyspark` or could I use my regular `jupyter notebook` and import the necessary things myself?

Answer (score 3):

Pyspark should be started with the `spark-cassandra-connector` package as described in the Spark Cassandra Connector [python docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md).

```
./bin/pyspark 
  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_$SPARK_SCALA_VERSION:$SPARK_VERSION
```

With this loaded you will be able to use any of the Dataframe operations already present inside of Spark on C* dataframes. [More details on options of using C* dataframes](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md).

To set this up to run with `jupyter notebook` just set up your env with the following properties.

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
```

And calling `pyspark` will start up a notebook correctly configured.

There is no need to use `pyspark-cassandra` unless you are interseted in working with RDDs in python which has a few performance pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

In Python connector is exposed `DataFrame` API. As long as `spark-cassandra-connector` is available and `SparkConf` contains required configuration there is no need for additional packages. You can simply specify the format and options:

```py
df = (sqlContext
    .read
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(table="mytable", keyspace="mykeyspace")
    .load())
```

If you wan to use plain SQL you can register `DataFrame` as follows:

```py
df.registerTempTable("mytable")

## Optionally cache
sqlContext.cacheTable("mytable")

sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable group by beamstamp")
```

Advanced features of the connector, like `CassandraRDD` are not exposed to Python so if you need something beyond `DataFrame` capabilities then `pyspark-cassandra` may prove useful.

Comment: OK thanks. Is it possible (as in Scala) to have direct access to the tables via the SQL api?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. You can of course `registerTempTable` as usual. Also, there is no equivalent of `CassandraRDD`.

Comment: Alright. I'll post some code later on to make sure I got it right.